# ¿Cambiar de idioma en Unity dependiendo del idioma del dispositivo sin diccionarios?

Tags: unity, idioma

Tengo una aplicación en `Unity` con muchísimo texto, tanto que si lo quiero hacer en 10 idiomas mediante `diccionario` es imposible pues tardaría días y días en traductir todo y hacer cententas de variables asignadas a cada texto...

Lo que estoy buscando y no encuentro, es traducir el texto directamente dependiendo el idioma del dispositivo del usuario, es decir, if (el dispositivo del usuario está en ingles) = usar toda la app en inglés.

La primera parte es fácil, `if (Application.systemLanguate == English)` , pero la segunda parte no sé cómo referencia que todo lo escrito en unity se traduzca a inglés por ejemplo. Pienso que sí que se puede porque está escrito por mi, son letras, no son fotos, pero no logro encontrar ni hacer nada sin diccionario, creo que se me escapa algo...